# Show that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x} (x>0)$ is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ a continuous function for $x\ge 0$, $f'(x)$ exists for $x>0$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'$ increasing. Show that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x} (x>0)$ is increasing.

I would like to know if my proof holds, please.

As $f'$ exists and increasing, $f$ is convex. Consider the interval $0<x<b$ and by convex function property we have the following inequality:

$\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\le \dfrac{f(b)}{b}$

which holds $\forall \ 0<x<b$. And as $f$ is continuous for $x\ge 0$ and $b$ is an arbitrary point (respecting the inequality), we can conclude that $g(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: Not sure that it's a complete proof. Probably i should have considered an interval $0<a<x$, so the inequality becomes: $\frac{f(a)}{a}\le \frac{f(x)}{x}\le \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and then conclude that $g$ is increasing as a denominator in the last part of the inequality must be positif and the inequality holds for all $0<a<x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is correct.

You could improve readability by stating that for a convex map the slope of the line joining a fixed point with abscissa $a$ to a point with abscissa $x \gt a$ increases with $x$. Applying that in your case with $a=0$ and knowing that

$$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x- 0} = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$ you get that $g$ is increasing.

The introduction of $b$ seems useless to me.

Comment: Alright, thank you. But does my inequality works really? Even if $x$ and $b$ are arbitrary, it could be that $f(b)/b$ is a max of the function, so it doesn't really prove that $g$ is increasing. Check my comment under my post, please.

Comment: The problem is how do you relate $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ to the convexity of $f$?

Comment: As $f$ is convex and we consider $0<a<x$ we have: $\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a-0}\le\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\le\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and this inequality you can obtain from the inequality of convex function definition.

Comment: @Daniil Yes. What I mentioned in my answer is that for readability, it would be good that you state that in your proof.

Comment: Ah, alright. Sorry didn’t understand what you meant. So my proof is correct? Even if I mention $b$?

Comment: Yes $x \lt b$ implies $f(x)/x \lt f(b) / b$ is the definition of increasing.

Answer (score 0):

The assumptions implies that $f$ is convex. Therefore if $a<b $ we have $$f(a)=f(b\frac{a}{b} ) \leq \left(1-\frac{a}{b}\right) f(0) +\frac{a}{b} f(b) $$